# search a 2 dimensional array in java

Tags: java, arrays

How does one iterate through a two dimensional array search for [ ] [Name]?

When the Name is found the Index should be returned so that I can change the values in that array.

[Index] [Values].

Also, how does the syntax look for the storing to the array found? [ ] [index]. Loop through index and set a value. [0] [1] = blah.

Thanks

Comment: Please reformulate your question. "Two-dimensional arrays" in Java are just arrays of arrays, so if you have `String[][] matrix = ...`, then the first dimension `matrix[i]` has type `String[]`, not `String`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes it's easier and always cleaner to put the search in a separate method:

```
 private Point find2DIndex(Object[][] array, Object search) {

    if (search == null || array == null) return null;

    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < array.length; rowIndex++ ) {
       Object[] row = array[rowIndex];
       if (row != null) {
          for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < row.length; columnIndex++) {
             if (search.equals(row[columnIndex])) {
                 return new Point(rowIndex, columnIndex);
             }
          }
       }
    }
    return null; // value not found in array
 }
```

This will return the first match only. If you need all, collect all points in a List and return that list at the end.

---

Usage:

```
private void doSomething() {
  String[][] array = {{"one", "1"},{"two","2"}, {"three","3"}};
  Point index = find2DIndex(array, "two");

  // change one value at index
  if (index != null)
     array[index.x][index.y] = "TWO";

  // change everything in the whole row
  if (index != null) {
     String[] row = array[index.x];
     // change the values in that row
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Updated due to your comment:

```
for(String[] subarray : array){
   int foundIndex = -1;
   for(int i = 0; i < subarray.length; i++){
      if(subarray[i].equals(searchString)){
         foundIndex = i;
         break;
      }
   } 
   if(foundIndex != -1){
      // change all values that are not at position foundIndex
      for(int i = 0; i < subarray.length; i++){
         if(i != foundIndex){
            subarray[i] = "something";
         }
      } 
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer, so that you will have the index where the string was found.

Answer (score 3):

the most basic way is to

```
for(int xIndex = 0 ; xIndex < 3 ; xIndex++){
for(int yIndex = 0 ; yIndex < 3 ; yIndex++){
      if(arr[xIndex][yIndex].equals(stringToSearch)){
             System.out.println("Found at"+ xIndex +"," + yIndex);

             for(int remainingIndex = 0 ; remainingIndex  < 3 ; remainingIndex++  ){
                    arr[xIndex][remainingIndex]="NEW VALUES";
             }
             break;
      }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That is half my question. ;P So If I find the searchedItem how do I set the rest of the values for that array. Lets say searchedItem was at [0][0] searchedItem will be at index 0 of all the arrays. [0][0],[1][0] etc. I then want to edit the values of [0][1],[0][2],[0][3]? Thanks

Comment: @alJaree you just need to iterate other loop inside if to do editting , let me update

Comment: Thanks. I have the values hardcoded to variables.These values are sent over a socket in binary. So they are converted to String, Split and then each token is set to a variable. I want to set the indexes of the found array to the values. I know the index for the variables. [foundArray] [name] = Name, [foundArray] [size] = size etc. Where is the found array index to use out of a loop? thanks

Comment: No worries. Andreas answered it correctly. Thanks for the help.